# Error:- @ng-bootstrap\ng-bootstrap\datepicker\datepicker-navigation.d.ts.NgbDatepickerNavigation.html

Tags: datetimepicker, ng-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker, angular7

I am getting error as I have updated to angular7?

### Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
            "@angular/animations": "^7.0.3",
            "@angular/common": "^7.0.3",
            "@angular/compiler": "^7.0.3",
            "@angular/core": "^7.0.3",
            "@angular/forms": "^7.0.3",
            "@angular/http": "^7.0.3",
            "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.0.3",
            "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.0.3",
            "@angular/platform-server": "^7.0.3",
            "@angular/router": "^7.0.3",
            "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.9",
            "@types/lodash": "^4.14.116",
            "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
            "core-js": "^2.5.7",
            "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
            "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
            "ng-connection-service": "^1.0.4",
            "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^6.3.1",
            "ngx-toastr": "^9.1.0",
            "ngx-ui-switch": "^1.6.0",
            "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
            "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
            "web-animations-js": "2.3.1",
            "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
        },
        "devDependencies": {
            "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.10.5",
            "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
            "@angular/cli": "^7.0.5",
            "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.0.3",
            "@angular/language-service": "^7.0.3",
            "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
            "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.11",
            "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
            "@types/node": "^10.12.6",
            "codelyzer": "^4.5.0",
            "jasmine-core": "^3.3.0",
            "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
            "karma": "^3.1.1",
            "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
            "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
            "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.3",
            "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
            "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
            "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
            "protractor": "^5.4.1",
            "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.5",
            "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
            "tslint": "^5.11.0",
            "typescript": "^3.1.6",
            "webpack": "^4.20.2"
        }
    }
```

Above error occuring while I am running command:-

```
ng build --configuration=qa
```

How to solve this issue while using `ng build --configuration=qa` ?
This error occuring when running  `ng build --configuration=qa` ?

### Error:-

> ERROR in
>   node_modules\@ng-bootstrap\ng-bootstrap\datepicker\datepicker-navigation.d.ts.NgbDatepickerNavigation.html(3,67):
>   : An expression of type 'void' cannot be tested for truthiness

Comment: Angular 7 compatible bootstrap library info is available in https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started Angular(7.0.0) == ng-bootstrap (4.x.x)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I updated the '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap' package to version 4 and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 7):

try this `npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@latest`

Answer (score 0):

I updated the '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap' package to version 4 and it solved the problem.

After

> npm i @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@4.2.2

prod build is successful.

This issue I faced on migration from 6 to 7 transition of angular update prod build